# React - How to include react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I'm new to react and I want to use the router to navigate bet pages/components. I couldn't find too much but was following one tutorial online but I don't think I'm doing it right as I'm only getting errors.

1. When I import router and then have this line:  `const { Router, Route ...} = ReactRouter;` it gives me errors and I'm not sure how to do it right.
2. I'm not sure where to put the router path. I always see its being put into `ReactDOM:render(...)`. I only render in my index.js file and it just seems wrong to me to put it there as I feel I should only render the App component (for good practice). Am I wrong?

Thanks a lot!

App.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import Router from'react-router'

    const { Router, Route, IndexRoute, IndexLink, hashHistory, Link } = ReactRouter;
    class App extends React.Component {
      render () {
        return (
             <div>
              <button><Link to="/page">Page</Link></button>

                Router history={ReactRouter.hashHistory}>
                   <Route path="/" component={App}>
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/page" component={Page}>
                   </Route>
                </Router>
             </div>
            );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

index.js:

```
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been some changes after React router V4, and you should make sure that the code examples you find are right for the version you are using.

I am using v4, and this is what I do:

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
....
....

<BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/" component={Login} />
        </Switch>  
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  My version is: "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2" and when I use your code, Im getting the error 'settings is not defined

Comment: oh yeah because settings is my component, obviously you should import and use your components instead.

Comment: import Settings from './routes/settings'; -- this is how I import the setting component... you should create and use your own

Comment: what is meant by settings?I don't understand what settings is or what you mean by settings from your component or create/use my own setting?

Comment: Setting is just a component I created, just as you created your "page" component, I guess: <Route path="/page" component={Page}>. You can/should remove the setting component line and use your own

Comment: ohh sorry I didn't see that in your code. That makes sense now. I somehow though 'setting' is some react router thing! In my button (where I want to navigate to my page, I added Link:   <button><Link to="/page">Page</Link></button> and also imported Link like that: import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-don'; but Im getting the error The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`. Is there something wrong in the way I use Link ?

Comment: Also I added the code that you provided insight my render(){} in my App.js component (just in case its wrong)

Comment: the code I gave you need to be inserted in the return part: render() { return(...code here...)}. And you shouldn't wrap your link in a button, the correct way is this: <Link to="/page">Page</Link>

Comment: When I added it to my return statement, Im getting the error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: That's a problem in your component, have a look at this post: https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/860

Comment: okay thank you! so the problem was this line: <Route path="/" component={App} /> so I probably should create another component who's only purpose is to return the router path and then import it in my App.js right? Another problem Im getting now since I removed that line of code is 2 errors with my Link: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`. and Cannot read property 'history' of undefined